# Confusion in Free Radical Reactions with alkenes

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, radicals

I was reading the free radical reactions, therein I saw two almost same(atleast that's what i think) but forming different products.

First, we have cyclohexene reacting with Br2 in presence of sunlight. The product it gives is 3-bromo cyclohexene. *The C=C bond doesn't break homolytically*

Second, We have Kharasch Effect (Anti Markovnikov Reaction), in which the C=C bond breaks homolytically .

I am kinda confused as to when we have to break the C=C bond and when we have to break C-H bond.

Comment: [Wohl-Ziegler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wohl%E2%80%93Ziegler_bromination) allylic bromination.